# Is it correct to save custom core data object using managedObjectContext property

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a managed object in core data. This is a custom object with all necessary managed properties. I want to know if it is correct if I call save method using the managedObjectContext property of the same object? When we create this object we pass a managedObjectContext to the initializer. Does this object saves the passed context in that property?

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Message", in: context)
let message = PopMessage(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
```

Now after modifying its properties can I call something like this?

```
message.managedObjectContext.save()
```

I find this more convenient but not sure if this will give desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine. Both contexts point to the same object and the result is the same.  The only issue to be aware of is that the managed object does not keep a strong pointer to the context.  So if the context has already left memory you will have problems.  This can happen if you create a context without assigning it to a variable, or pass around managedObject with blocks.